# I don't understand the Node.js architecture

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

We are considering `node.js` as a web platform. But I have one crucial question, because I think I don't get the architecture of `node.js`:

1. It looks like that by default you're forced to use their custom HTTP server, no WSGI or anything?!
2. It looks like that when doing some "real computation" in a response (not only some I/O), all the infrastructure is messed up and `ab -n ... -c ...` returns enormous times per request compared with e.g. Python -- Pyramid/Flask or whatever?!
3. So, authors of `node.js` assume that we're doing only I/O or I've missed something very basic?

Comment: You should read about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface. I'd be a tiny bit concerned if node.js used it.

Comment: @Kurt: We benchmarked Python vs. node.js.

Comment: Combine the phrasing above with your comments below and it appears that you are doing little but trolling, using this "question" as a chance to express your opinion.

Comment: @Phrogz No I am not, I am simply looking for the answer to the question how to make `node.js` using all the 16 cores on our server in the most natural way, if our tasks are not only I/O bound.

Comment: @James updated my answer to specifically address that latest comment.

Comment: I edited the title of this question to make it less troll-like.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. You contradict yourself: "by default" and "forced" are not compatible. You can use whatever HTTP library you want. The core `http` module may be thought of as a "default," but nothing stops you from using another.
2. JavaScript is a single-threaded language, and Node.js is a JavaScript runtime, not a web server that spawns a thread-per-response like many others. You can still do a thread per response if you want, and there are projects built on top of Node that do this, but you lose most of the benefits of Node. If you are doing computation-heavy stuff in response to a web request (and you have clients who are willing to wait for you to do it), you should spin off a separate thread via one of the many available solutions (web workers, threads-a-go-go, child_process, etc.).
3. The authors of Node.js assume you are writing a web server. Most of the things you do in a web server are, essentially, IO, whether that IO involves a filesystem, a database, or even a message bus used for queuing computationally-intensive tasks on other workhouse processes.

Looking over your question, you seem to have a basic misunderstanding of what Node.js is, if you're trying to integrate it with Python and WSGI. Node.js is for writing web servers, so trying to use it... alongside Python? inside Python? (I'm really not sure what you're trying to accomplish) makes little sense.

If your tasks are not only I/O bound, you should probably not be hosting those tasks on the same box as your web server. Thus, the message bus approach mentioned briefly in 3. But if you are determined to do so, and are sure that those tasks won't hog all the CPU, you should determine how often such tasks are prevalent. If they are on every web request, you should not use Node.js; you are giving up its most basic advantages, leaving only minor ones (like the ecosystem that's grown up around it). If they are rare, then you should spin them off in separate threads via the many methods available in 2.

Relevant: https://gist.github.com/2794861

Comment: ad 3, so it's true that `node.js`'s concept does not handle CPU-bound subtasks well. OK.

Comment: Not just Node.js, but JavaScript in general.

Comment: I didn't get your remark about Python, I only benchmarked Python vs. node.js and node.js was terrible for our benchmark.

Comment: Ah OK, it sounded like you were trying to use WSGI with Node, which (as @Kurt Spindler notes) makes no sense.

Comment: I guess, you're wrong in 2, node.js has some internal HTTP server (oh god... another one), I see no reason, why this HTTP server couldn't be multi-threaded.

Comment: This http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html is the proof that we are not the only ones with this problem.

Comment: In 2, I said that Node is not a web server that spawns threads-per-response. The reason it's not multi-threaded is because of the many benefits of async IO. Thread-per-response is extremely heavyweight. The cluster API is used for computationally intensive tasks, not for spawning a new thread for every HTTP request (which would be really dumb).

Answer (score 3):

If you are a Python-based shop, you might also want to consider [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com) which is an event-driven framework written in Python. Twisted is also able to defer long running blocking work to threads.

The most important thing is that you first define what you need and what your problem is. Do not jump on the new fancy thing just because everyone is talking about it. Look at your needs and use something that addresses them.

Answer (score 0):

I see there is a node.js module patterned after WSGI: [Strata](http://search.npmjs.org/#/strata)

Also, you can offload intensive computations to child processes: [Child Process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

Comment: Forking is a terrible operation, if child process means process, e.g. on Linux.

Comment: Yes, it means a child process. How intensive exactly is your intensive computation, that it manages to hurt your single-thread performance, but the fork cost is still comparatively large enough to be a problem for you?

Comment: Imagine 1000 requests per second, you have two CPUs with 6 cores each, so we naturally want a solution which uses all the CPUs. I mean, naturally -- no proxies of proxies.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html

You can run 6 node.js processes on a 6-core machine, and they will share the HTTP listener; though this is experimental extension, and I have no idea how exactly it would balance the requests between the processes.

Also, I see that you can run it as a FastCGI-like server: http://search.npmjs.org/#/NodeCGI

Or you can put together some custom solution with long-lived computational childs and some protocol to talk to them. You have too specific requirements to expect an out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: @lanzz I believe the load balancing is random done by kernel. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/nodejs/s04AKMHYTEA/5xEdFKjkIG0J